# Is there a GitHub like code-sharing service which does allow version control but isn't Git based?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, git, github, sharing

I use Windows 10 Home and I have a GitHub account with just one repository with about five code-oriented files (`.md` files these are).

As a **non** Git language user, I always used the GitHub GUI to CRUD these files and others.

I put code-oriented files in GitHub because I want to share them in general, because it helps me organize my files and because it allows reaching them quickly from search engines or even browser address bars.

### My problem

With time I understood I would like to edit the files outside GitHub GUI --- this could be from say `nano` text editor via shell after SSHING to the server, or from say Visual Studio Code as a substitute for the GitHub GUI.

But:

- The GitHub hosting service  is Git language based; hence:
   files cannot be edited in a `edit-and-save-and-that's-it` fashion as they would after SSHing into an environment and editing a file with a text editor such as `nano`.
- I am not a Git language user and with all humbleness and honestly, personally, at least now, I don't want to be.

Edit: By "Git language" I mean `Git commands issued at a command line`.

### My question

Is there a GitHub like code-sharing service which does allow version control but isn't Git based, so that CRUD operations would be available in it by an `edit-and-save-and-that's-it` methodology, either after SSHing (CLUI) or after browser login (GUI) or both?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are after (my fault), but would https://sourceforge.net/ help?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I kindly invite you to review the edit for this question; I thank you for your time so far.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica this might be a good suite for me but I feel overwhelmed with accounts and passwords and try to stay minimal as I can; I humbly expect an answer to come to know if I make a step to leave GitHub towards SorceForge (or anything else) or staying with GitHub. I take the time as this would be a great step for me.

Comment: Even after the edit, I don't really understand. What do you mean by "Git language"? You mean the Git commands issued at a command line? If that is your only "problem" with GitHub, then I strongly recommend you look into the GitHub integration features of many editors and IDEs, including Visual Studio Code; or dedicated client software such as GitHub Desktop, which greatly reduce the need to use Git commands at a command line. In other words, I recommend addressing your own tools and workflow, rather than the hosting service. GitHub is tough to beat as a sharing/storage platform.

Comment: If you are dead-set on migrating away from GitHub, you can at least get an idea of what's out there from [this Wikipedia roundup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source-code-hosting_facilities).

Comment: @JohnY hello - indeed I meant `Git commands issued at a command line`.

Comment: It might be good to edit your question to indicate that what you want to avoid is a command-line based system, or even a system which requires explicit steps to "commit", etc.  There are other version control options, like Mercurial, but they work basically like Git in that you have to issue commands to "save" each version.  It seems like what you want is more akin to Dropbox's versioning, where every time you save the file a new version is automatically created.

Comment: @BrenBarn thanks ; I do want to save versions as these will be backups of every change and it's good for me; I just want everything to be direct on the remote server without the need to download, change and reupload **never** --- whether from CLUI/TUI/GUI.